# Allow "Enter" key working but not breaking line given

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need to achieve that breakline works here, because you can type enter, but after you type again no breaking line is given.

i make this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FPN9w/

Here is the JS code.

```
$(function () {
    //you have to escaped the - character in a character class
    var cleanRx = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÜüñÑ¨´,.¿?%&$!¡ªº#"()\-_\/]/g;

    $('#title').keyup(function (e) {
        var which = e.which;

        //avoid useless replacements when <- and -> keys are pressed
        if (which === 39 || which === 37) return;

        this.value = this.value.replace(cleanRx, '');

    }).trigger('keyup'); //perform replacement on initial content (remove if uneeded)

    $('#description1').keyup(function (e) {
        var which = e.which;

        //avoid useless replacements when <- and -> keys are pressed
        if (which === 39 || which === 37 || which === 13) return;

        this.value = this.value.replace(cleanRx, '');

    }).trigger('keyup'); //perform replacement on initial content (remove if uneeded)

});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Might help you http://jsfiddle.net/FPN9w/1/, Here used `/[^a-zA-Z0-9 áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚÜüñÑ¨´,.¿?%&$!¡ªº#"()\n\r\-_\/]/g;`

Comment: Satpal pls make formal Answer, your fiddle is just what i need =) appreciate !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code in js

```
$('#description1').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

This is your updated JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pratbhoir/FPN9w/3/

Comment: Thanks maybe i ask wrong the question.. I need the enter key to work, i mean to add a breakline.. In the fiddle that you add, i cant just cant add a breakline .. thanks!!